# how to make MyBatis to using local DTD config file

Tags: mybatis

My server could not access mybatis dtd file url,when I download this:

```
curl -L http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd
```

It is aways blocked.The problem is my app could not started in my server, it aways blocked forever. The question is: How to make MyBatis using local dtd file？

Comment: FYI, MyBatis itself does not try to load the remote DTDs. It uses a custom [EntityResolver](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/bf01fee3dfd71e351c3b9660d8adb6384616f627/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/builder/xml/XMLMapperEntityResolver.java) that loads the DTDs from inside the JAR.

Comment: I read the code but how to explain the app start blocked when could not access the http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd url and I change the config it works?@ave

Comment: There must be something else (container? library?) that is trying to parse the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am downloaded MyBatis DTD file to local,and change my config:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "./mybatis-3-config.dtd">
```

It works.